# Change 'color scheme' in Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I don't want to use the default color's in a donut chart in raphael.js. The default is something like Red - Orange - Yellow.... etc.

Ideally, I'd like to set up custom colors, like so:

```
colors: [
    '#f00',
    '#0f0',
    '#00f'
];
```

I've got a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L6aGk/1/), with the fill variables set as `color` and `bcolor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pretty close, please see my revision here: http://jsfiddle.net/9GN6z/

1.Add your custom color before angle=0:

```
var colors= ['#f00', '#0f0','#00f']
```

2.Replace

```
bcolor = Raphael.hsb(start, 1, 1)
```

with

```
bcolor = colors[j%colors.length]
```

to apply your custom color. Hope it would help :)